# CSS pseudo content arrow has bevel on phone

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am using the CSS escaped character ▶ (\25b6) in a before pseudo element as part of a play button for a video.

The arrow looks fine on all of my desktop browsers:
[image: arrow on desktop (without bevel)]

but when i load it up on Chrome on my android phone (Galaxy Note 3) it has magical (and ugly) bevel on it:

[image: arrow on phone (with bevel)]

**The CSS (SCSS):**

```
.play {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgba(black, 0.3);
    box-shadow: none;
    &:before {
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        content: "\25b6";
        display: block;
        font-size: 2.75rem;
        width: 4rem;
        height: 4rem;
        line-height: 1.5;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        background-color: rgba(black, 0.8);
        transition: transform 1s;
    }
}
```

**Question:**

How do I remove this bevel? I know I could create the arrow using [css triangles](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) (tested and it works) but would like to avoid the extra markup if possible.

I guess I am more curious as to how to override the styles chrome is applying to this character, rather than workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use FontAwesome... it has all the symbol glyphs you would use, including the play icon ;)

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I am using a font icon I created with grunt-webfont and could add a play icon to the set. I more curious however as to how to override the styles chrome is applying to this character.

Comment: In that case... everything's about the render. Try to reduce the antialias when rendering the glyph. It seems to be that.

Comment: How would I 'reduce' antialias through CSS?

Comment: with "font-smooth"
http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspfontsmooth.htm

Comment: Im not sure font smoothing will solve this issue, I already have font-smoothing: antialiased; applied to this element, will try removing it.

Comment: No difference with different smoothing values.